# How to add fetching image from MySQL server to existing Android code

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have a source code from here https://freebieslearning.net/android-2/android-find-nearby-user/ which fetch and display location of registered persons and distances between the user and the registered user. Am wondering how will i add image to the data so when it fetch the data images are also included in it. Let me paste the code here

```
<?PHP
include_once("Connection.php");
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];

$query = "select * from(SELECT name,latitude,longitude,round((((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) *     cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * 
cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344),1) as distance
FROM location) as temp order by distance";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) == true) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

MyData.java:

```
package com.example.sumit.nearbyapp;

public class MyData {
    String name;
    double latitude, longitude, distance;

    public MyData(String name, double latitude, double longitude, double distance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}

package com.example.sumit.nearbyapp;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<MyData> my_data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.name.setText(my_data.get(position).getName().toString());
        holder.distance.setText(Double.toString(my_data.get(position).getDistance()));
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%s,%s (%s)",
                Double.toString(my_data.get(position).getLatitude()), 
            Double.toString(my_data.get(position).getLongitude()),my_data.get(position).getName());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView distance;
        public TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map);
            distance = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}

package com.example.sumit.nearbyapp;

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}

package com.example.sumit.nearbyapp;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String latitude, longitude;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    private List<MyData> data_list;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading . . . ");

        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());

            data_list  = new ArrayList<>();
            load_data_from_server();
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
    }

    private void load_data_from_server() {
        String url = "http://vga.ramstertech.com/loc/location.php?latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude+"";
        pd.show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
                        Double latitude = jsonobject.getDouble("latitude");
                        Double longitude = jsonobject.getDouble("longitude");
                        Double distance = jsonobject.getDouble("distance");

                        MyData data = new MyData(name.toString(), latitude, longitude, distance);

                        data_list.add(data);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pd.hide();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    pd.hide();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: CAN SOMEONE HELP ME OUT

Answer (score 0):

you can add image to it by first creating a database column name "image" and a folder "image" or "uploads"

```
package com.example.sumit.nearbyapp;


public class MyData {
String name, image;
double latitude,longitude,distance;

public MyData(String image, String name, double latitude,double longitude,double distance){
  this.name = name;
  this.image = image;
  this.distance = distance;
  this.latitude = latitude;
  this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getImge() {
    return image;
}

public void setImge(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

}

under customadapter

```
package com.example.sumit.nearbyapp;


public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<MyData> my_data;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.my_data = my_data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {



    holder.name.setText(my_data.get(position).getName().toString());
    holder.distance.setText(Double.toString(my_data.get(position).getDistance()));
    //holder.image.setText(my_data.get(position).getImge().toString());
    String fullUrl = "http://192.168.0.199/uploads/" + "product/" + "iPhone 6  Black" + ".jpg";
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(fullUrl)
            .centerCrop().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.image);

    //Glide.with(context).load(my_data.get(position).getImge()).fitCenter().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.image);


    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%s,%s (%s)",
            Double.toString(my_data.get(position).getLatitude()), Double.toString(my_data.get(position).getLongitude()),my_data.get(position).getName());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return my_data.size();
}

public  class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView distance;
    public TextView name;
    public ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageDownloaded);
        distance=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}
```

}

```
<?PHP
 //include_once("connect_database.php");
include_once("Connection.php");
$latitude=$_GET['latitude'];
$longitude=$_GET['longitude'];

$query = "select * from(SELECT        name,image,latitude,longitude,round((((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * 
sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * 
cos(((".$longitude."- `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344),1) as distance
FROM location) as temp order by distance";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) == true){
 $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Hope it works